# Java/Android - Saving an audio/voice file on the server from different apps

Tags: java, audio, voice

I'm trying to create an app similar to WhatsApp. Currently, working on voice messaging part of it. My app has to store the audio files on the server. FYI - I would like to support the same file formats as WhatsApp.

I am new to media implementation and have referred [Java Sound APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) and other questions here on StackOverflow and cannot make a decision on how to get started on this. Can someone please push me in the right direction?

The questions I have now are -

1. Is it right to have an external web service to both Android & iPhone apps to store the media files to server or should I do it from the apps itself?
2. If external web service, are Java Sound APIs the right APIs to use? And, how do I make sure I support all file types (eg: m4a, aac, mp3, opus) because [AudioFileFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFileFormat.Type.html) supports only WAVE, AU, AIFF, AIFC, SND?

Thanks.